# Header on Individual Posts

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to be able to customize my header on individual posts on my blogspot website. Currently, the header is set to:

(Post Name) Free Craft Patterns, Templates, and DIY Tutorials. I want to take away the plural from these, without affecting my other main pages. Is there a way to do this? Here is my existing code:

```
<title>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> <?php } ?> 
<?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',true)); ?> <?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name'));  ?>  
</title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo ucwords(str_replace('s', '', get_bloginfo('name'))) ?>
```

Comment: How would I get it so that it only does this for individual post titles? Would I need another if statement.... if (is_single()) ??

Comment: I haven't worked with WordPress for a while, but if you're using this header on all your pages, then yeah, you'll need to check is_single. You could use the ternary operator to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: Exactly... `if ( is_home() || is_single() )`, if I'm understanding your requirements correctly.